# Liferay 6.1 Access page for an organization

Tags: liferay

I'm very new to Liferay.
I have to make a portal with 3 pages: Home, Restau1 and Restau2. Also I need to specify 3 Admins: the main Admin, admin of the Restau1 Page and Restau2 Page. They will change the content of these pages.
I've created two organizations org1 and org2 and add users to them. And I do not know how to "tie" these users to the specific page.
Please, help

Answer (score 0):

Reading the User Guide is inevitable for everyone dipping a toe into Liferay. Roles, permissions, user groups are even more fundamental. After reading this chapter, you will not only know what to do, but you will also understand the principles and mechanisms behind functions.

http://www.liferay.com/hu/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/administering-liferay-portal